# Share dialog Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I follow this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/

but I don't know where is the variable "callback" on this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I don't know what it is. It isn't declared anywhere in the tutorial.
I need help, please!

Comment: did you see the topic under setup?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. I followed the tutorial and the error is: callback cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: first you need to go through the login tutorial and then you need to follow the share tutorial.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

Comment: `private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};` that is your callback

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `UiLifecycleHelper` is of type `Session.StatusCallback`, which is defined in the [first part of the tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#step2).  It's under **Step 2: Set Up authentication change triggers** I believe.