# sample facebook sharing api android

Tags: android, facebook

Can you help me on understanding(the correct way) how facebook api should be applied in an android apps. I currently followed the official site of facebook developer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share.

I want to embed the share button in my application but when I follow the link above. I'm having error in this line cause I don't know where to get the callback.

```
@Override
```

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback); <this callback
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

}

I would really appreciate if you can give a tutorial that is up to date on how to implement facebook api.

thanks in advance.

chkm8

Comment: What is the error? Have you defined "private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper"? Have you added Facebook SDK to your workspace in Eclipse?

Comment: I already solved this issue, I just did not follow the entire tutorial in facebook dev. And also this topic was already discussed in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509529/share-dialog-facebook-on-android.

Thanks for for the fast response Kasra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UiLifecycleHelper is the class that would manage the life cycle of your request to the facebook api. It will give you update or response of your query or request through callback. Below is a sample implementation of facebook login with callback. [For detailed instruction follow this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2) .

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

---

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            //when login
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            //do when no connection or logout
        }
    }
};
```

In my question posted above, I want to use the SHARE method of facebook. Here is my solution:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "SAMPLE POST");
    params.putString("caption","SAMPLE CAPTION");
    params.putString("description", _sub.getDefinition());
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                       FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                        //                              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Posted story, id: "+postId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Publish cancelled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error posting story",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

---

```
Button temp = new Button(getActivity());
    temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishFeedDialog();
        }
    });
```

For more detailed instruction on how to share in facebook ,[follow this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share).

***NOTE: Please vote me up to have positive contribution